# What are different forces acting on a planet which may be related to axial tilts?

Tags: solar-system, planetary-science, planetary-systems, gravitation, axial-tilt

In our solar system, we see that the axis of rotation of planets is tilted forex. The axial tilt of Venus is near 179 degrees. Venus, Uranus, and Pluto have large values of axial tilt(more than 90 degrees). I have two questions -

Question 1. I know that it is believed that these axial tilts are due to collisions with big objects. But all planets have axial tilt(may it be more or less), so does that mean all planets suffered from a collision with something?

Question 2. There is no solid evidence yet that the axial tilt of planets is due to collisions.  If we assume that axial tilt is not due to collision, then what are various forces acting on a planet which may be responsible for axial tilt? I mean gravitational interaction of the planet with its moon is one of the factors responsible for axial tilt. Which are the other forces that act on a planet in general(leave for now whether these forces are responsible for axial tilt or not). ?